# Append div with Pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pagination

I want pagination by next and previous button of each appended div.
I have append div_2 in show_form div.it is working properly.but i need help for pagination of div by next and previous button.Please help me out.

Here is my Html

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").on("click", ".btns", function() {
    $(".show_form").append($(".div_2").html());

    $('.div_2').animate({
      'margin-left': '1000px'
    }, function() {
      $(".div_2").remove()
      $('#show_form').attr("id", "div_2");
      $('#div_2').addClass('div_2');
      $('#div_2').removeClass('show_form');
      $("#div_2").after(function() {
        return "<div id='show_form' class='show_form'></div>"
      });
      $('#show_form').addClass('show_form');
    })
    $('.show_form').show("slow");
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div_2" class="div_2">
  this is div 2
  <form class="this_form">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="button" value="buttons" />
  </form>
</div>
<div id="show_form" class="show_form">
</div>
<button class="btns" type="button" id="btnn">add more</button>
```

Comment: go to this link and analyse http://jsfiddle.net/3u64cx2s/9/

Comment: I have also tried it.but it is also not working.

Comment: after appending back button is not working neither next button.all divs are hiding

Comment: I think that you must add your next and prev buttons out of the dots ul.

Comment: No i have added inside the ul. please provide me the correct code.

Comment: go through this link , you will get an idea https://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/s7ac8aq3/4/

Comment: These are normally added to pagination.i am facing problem with pagination of append div.